# Arrange the following growth rates in increasing order: $O (n (\log n)^2), O (35^n), O(35n^2 + 11), O(1), O(n \log n)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I want to Arrange the following growth rates in increasing order

This order are following : $O (n (\log n)^2), O ((35)^n), O(35n^2 + 11), O(1), O(n \log n)$

Please give me idea how to arrange growth rates in increasing order

Regards,
Jatin

Comment: Any guess for which would be the largest and smallest growth rate? For the remaining ones, try to order them and use limits for $n \to \infty$ to assess which growth rate is bigger than the other.

Comment: no idea which was largest and smallest.

Comment: One of them stays constant when $n$ is increasing, that one might have the smallest growth rate.

Comment: i haven't idea can you give me answer?

Comment: @JatinGadhiya You need to show *some* working. Try substituting $n = 1, 2, \cdots$ and try to figure out the growth rates of the functions.

Comment: Have you learned what for example O (n log n) actually means? Are you for example in a course where you are supposed to be able to answer this question? If not, you need to learn what this all means, once you do, it's quite simple. If yes, consider a different career.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are talking about [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), you should discard the constants, which means that $O(35n^2+11)$ should be written as $O(n^2)$.

what you are interested in is the size at big numbers. And here is a rule to remember:

$$O(n^n)>O(n!)>O(\alpha^n)>O(n^\alpha)>O(log(n))>O(1)$$

Where $\alpha$ is a constant.

If you are not sure, then you can just insert a big $n$ and check which is the biggest ($n=100$):

- $35^{100} = 2.5\cdot10^{154}$
- $100^2 = 10^{4}$
- $100{\cdot}log^2(100)=400$
- $100{\cdot}log(100)=200$
- $1 = 1$ for every $n$

Showing you that $O(35^n) > O(n^2) > O(nlog^2(n))>O(nlog(n))>O(1)$

Comment: Using a big $n$ might not work, since $n$ must be sufficiently large and one might not fill in a sufficiently large enough value. Think of $O(1.01^n)$ and $O(n^4)$ at $n = 1000$, where $1.01^{1000} \approx 20959$ and $1000^4 = 10^{12}$ would lead you to believe that $O(n^4) > O(1.01^n)$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1.01^n}{n^4} = \infty$, which correctly gives $ O(1.01^n) > O(n^4)$. I suggest an edit to the answer to be careful when one uses that approach.

Comment: You are correct with the example, that is why I gave the rule at the start which says that $O(\alpha^n)>O(n^\alpha)$ for every constant. Calculating the $lim_{n \to \infty}$can be difficult/long at some times. Putting in a number is much easier. You do need to know the "right number" to put, but usually it's not that hard to find such a number.

Answer (score 2):

If

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty,
\end{align}

then the growth rate of $f(n)$ is larger than the growth rate of $g(n)$. Vice versa, if

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0,
\end{align}

then the growth rate of $f(n)$ is smaller than the growth rate of $g(n)$.

Thus, the largest growth rate is $O(35^n)$, since

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{35^n}{n \log^2 n} &= \infty, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{35^n}{35n^2 + 11} &= \infty, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{35^n}{1} &= \infty, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{35^n}{n \log n} &= \infty.
\end{align}

And you can do the rest yourself.